# Duplicate class com.google.api.Advice

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, protocol-buffers

I have two backends that support grpc comunication.

For each one of them I have created a simple android project that has this build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName rootProject.version
        minSdkVersion 15
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

configurations {
    pubReleaseCompile
}


android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            proto {
                srcDir '../../protos/folder'
            }
        }
    }

}

protobuf {

    protoc { artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.2' }
    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src/generated"
    plugins {
        javalite { artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0" }
        grpc { artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.25.0' }
    }
   
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.plugins {
                javalite {}
                grpc {
                    option 'lite'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    protobuf files('../protos')
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.25.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.25.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.25.0'
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    protobuf 'com.google.api.grpc:proto-google-common-protos:1.18.0'
}
```

The clients generation works fine, but when I tried to import both of them in an android app at the same time lots of errors like this appear

`Duplicate class com.google.type.TimeZoneOrBuilder found in modules jetified-backend1-runtime.jar (backend1) and jetified-backend2-runtime.jar (backend2)`

It looks like both grpc clients have the same google classes.

In my android app I have the following build.gradle

```
    implementation ('backend1-client'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.grpc', module: 'proto-google-common-protos'
    }

    implementation 'backend2-client'
```

I tried lots of exclude groups combinations but none of them worked

I am trying now exclude the google files from the generateProtoTasks. Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit 1: The problem is not in the protos. I think the problem is that the protos of both backends share some imports (for example import "google/api/annotations.proto") which then generates the duplicated classes

Update: I joined all the protos into one repo and generated the clients there. That seems to work. I could import this repo in my android app without problems. I was able to do this because I have ownership of both backends

Comment: Did you define that class? If so is renaming it in one of the clients and option?

Comment: Nope, the protos of both backends have the same imports, for example import "google/api/annotation.proto" . I think those shared imports are generating this problem

Comment: What about combining the clients under the same imports? If this is not practical, what about ignoring them using Gradle? (cannot add code here, posted as an answer).

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that I should join all the protos in one place? That was an option I was evaluating, but I would like to keep them separated. About the ignoring using gradle, I would like to know how, I couldn't achieve it yet

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of joining them together.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions are either to combine the code under the same import or somehow to ignore that class in Gradle like this (I am not sure exactly how as the code generated from the `.proto` file is creating the problem):

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude '**/com.google.type.TimeZoneOrBuilder.class'
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm genting the same error Duplicate class com.google.type.TimeZoneOrBuilder found in modules jetified-ads-cads-client-0.0.2-alpha-runtime.jar (com.tfg.libs:ads-cads-client:0.0.2-alpha) and jetified-ads-exchange-client-0.0.2-alpha-runtime.jar (com.tfg.libs:ads-exchange-client:0.0.2-alpha)

Comment: This is more like a pointer than a solution as I have no idea where the class is located.

Comment: Tried lots of things without success. I ended creating a new repo with all the protos and generated the client there. That seems to work . Not the best solution for me though